# Dask array rfft doesn't seems to work

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to do some real fft in some large arrays and decided to give 
dask a try. I've run into a problem where the function dask.array.rfft does not seems to work no matter what I do. Here's a minimal example.

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import dask

print('Dask version: {}'.format(dask.__version__))

x = np.random.random((10, 10))
dx = da.from_array(x, chunks=(2, x.shape[1]))
dx_fft = da.fft.fft(dx)
dx_ifft = da.fft.ifft(dx_fft)
dx_ifft.compute()
print('Regular fft worked out just fine.')

dx = da.from_array(x, chunks=(2, x.shape[1]))
dx_rfft = da.fft.rfft(dx, axis=1)
dx_irfft = da.fft.irfft(dx_rfft, axis=1)
dx_irfft.compute()
print('Real fft worked out just fine.')
```

The output of the program is.

```
Dask version: 0.7.5
Regular fft worked out just fine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 16, in <module>
    dx_irfft = da.fft.irfft(dx_rfft, axis=1)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/fft.py", line 35, in func
    chunks=chunks)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 449, in map_blocks
    result = atop(func, out_ind, *args, name=name, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 1420, in atop
    chunkss, arrays = unify_chunks(*args)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 1342, in unify_chunks
    for a, i in arginds]
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 1141, in rechunk
    return rechunk(self, chunks)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/rechunk.py", line 232, in rechunk
    return Array(x2, temp_name, chunks, dtype=x.dtype)
  File "/home/heitor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/toolz/functoolz.py", line 348, in memof
    raise TypeError("Arguments to memoized function must be hashable")
TypeError: Arguments to memoized function must be hashable
```

Whatever operation I try to do with dx_rfft, it returns the same error. I've tried Pythons 2 and 3 and both have the same issue.
Am I missing something or is this a bug of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not occur on dask master. The easiest solution is probably to install from there. The easiest way to do this is to

```
$ conda remove dask
$ pip install git+git://github.com/blaze/dask.git # might need root
```

Or you can create a fresh conda environment so your system dask does not have to be replaced with the potentially broken development version

```
$ conda create -n myenv dask  #create "myenv" environment and install dask + depedencies
$ source activate myenv
(myenv)$ conda remove dask
(myenv)$ pip install git+git://github.com/blaze/dask.git
```

Comment: Funny thing that the conda package seems to be broken. Anyways, installing from git did work. Thanks a million.

Comment: @DaddyCool Glad to help. I think this was a bug in the 0.7.5 release so the pip package is probably broken too. Would you mind "accepting" my answer if it resolves the issue?